What voltage comes from a standard 6.3 mm instrument cable?
I am designing an electric percussion instrument using various metal strings and objects that are hit my solenoids. Pickups record the sound.I need to know what kind of voltage and current instrument cables output, so I can choose the correct parts

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level

It depends to which input you want to connect to - instrument inputs like guitars are, mic inputs like dynamic mics, line inputs like for line level outputs. If you are asking what voltages your pickups output, we don't know what pickups you bought and what they are supposed to be connected into.

@Mattman944 Unlikely linking to that page helps at all, like many times before, it creates more confusion like before.

@Justme I want it to connect to a standard fender guitar cable

@Crisps The cable is irrelevant. To which device the other end of the cable is connected to, an instrument-level input, a mic-level input, a line-level input, a headphone-level input, a speaker-level input, etc? And you need to say the make and model of the pickups you bought to find a manual which says what they output.

@Crisps Cables don't output voltage. It's the Pickups that generate a signal that is transmitted via cable. You're also not only interested in the Voltage that you get but also the impedance of the signal. So look at the datasheet of your pickup carefully. And also research a bit on how to prevent noise from overpowering your signal.

@Justme, sorry. Plugged into a guitar amp

@Crisps Great. Now what pickup you have, magnetic, piezoelectric, optical, etc, make/model etc?

@Justme magnetic

@Crisps Why is it so hard to get the information requested? What pickup it is and what are it's parameters? What do you know about the pickup you have not told yet?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no standard. The connector is just a connector. The correct level depends on the circuit at the other end. There are some "typical" values:

if the circuit at the other end is a "domestic" piece of audio gear (i.e. a line input of a hifi amp) : -10dbV
if the circuit is a "professional" line input (e.g. an audio mixer) there should be a gain trim which will allow you to adjust, you don't have to worry too much as long as your are giving -10dBV or more).

In reality, the output of your circuit is more likely to be determined by the available power supplies and type of signal you are generating. You can provide a level control at the output to reduce if needed. Also you do need to consider balanced and unbalanced connections.

If it is a passive pickup (e.g. guitar pickup) intended to be plugged into guitar amp then it outputs neither "domestic" or "pro" levels but "instrument" level.

but we are talking about what the circuit goes into, as far as I can tell. Yes, if we are going into a guitar amp the level would be different again, Same for a mic amp. The OP seems to be implying however that he has some kind of preamp and wants to know what its output should be. At least that is how I read it, it is indeed a bit vague.
